# Win32: Capturing desktop screenshots asynchronously

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, directx, directx-9

I am using a pretty common way to capture screenshots using Direct3D and encode them in an .mp4 video.

```
while (true)
{
HRESULT hr = pDevice->GetFrontBufferData(0, pSurface);

//code to create and send the sample to a IMFSinkWriter
}
```

It works despite being painfully slow (it's only good for 15 fps or so) but there's a major problem: I have to manually calculate each sample's timestamp and video length ends up as being incorrect and dependent on CPU speed.

Is there anyway to capture screenshot using a callback after a fixed interval of time (say 30 fps), without having to use the infinite loop?

Comment: Why don't you make a video as VFR(Variable Frame Rate)?

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33946441/11128312), which may help you.